# Gazebo on ubuntu of virtual machine, no response

Tags: ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

My gazebo on virtual machine is not stable. Every time I click insert and then add path, the software will have no response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing any issue in adding a path then use `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` variable.

You can check the current value of `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` typing:

```sh
echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
```

To add path:

```sh
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:<path to your model>
```

You can add this command in your `.bashrc` file so that every time you open a new terminal this variable will be set automatically.